# ie disregards anchors

Tags: internet-explorer, anchor

I have an anchor on my webpage:

```
<a name="here"></a>
```

and I link to it as usual:  http://mysite.com/mypage.aspx#here

Which works just fine in FF but for some reason it doesn't scroll to the anchor in internet explorer.

What now? What cunning hack do I need to employ to solve this mystery of the ages? (Darn that ie browser)

Comment: What version of IE? Does this example work in your version of IE?
http://alphaentry.com/index.php?module=features&action=emergency#spot

Comment: ie 8 and the sample you provided does scroll down regardless of the # sign in the url or not. Bad sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an empty anchor shouldn't it be < a name="here" />
or more correctly < a id="here" name="here />

Comment: That did solve it! Not the id-part but removing the </a> and inserting a / in the a-tag.

Thanks.

Comment: The ID attribute is really only needed for XHTML and/or Javascript getElementById I generally use both for compatibility.